# Calling a function on the start of a JavaFX project using SceneBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I created a GUI for my project using SceneBuilder and I set up all the button ID's and created a controller for the FXML file. I want to have a live clock running in the text area on launch and throughout the program. This is my first time using FXML to create a project in JavaFX so I'm confused as to where I should place this code. Normally the code works in a simple program without FXML and it is this code:

```
package com.example;
import example; 

public class Layout extends Application {

         TextArea clock;

public void start(Stage stage) throws FileNotFoundException {  
         
         clock = new TextArea();
         clock.setEditable(false);
          BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
          bp.setTop(clock);
 
          refreshClock();

         Scene scene = new Scene(bp);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
   }
}

  private void refreshClock()
    {
        Thread refreshClock = new Thread()
           {  
              public void run()
              {  
                while (true)
                {
                    Date dte = new Date();
        
                    String topMenuStr = "       " + dte.toString();                       
                    clock.setText(topMenuStr); 
                           
                    try
                    {
                       sleep(3000L);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  
                }  // end while ( true )
                 
            } // end run thread
         };

         refreshClock.start();
    }
```

When I attempt to do it my current progress in my Ui controller class, nothing pops up in the Text Area despite what code I do and I'm not sure what to do next. Should this code be in my main .java file? Here is what I tried:

```
package application;

import java.util.Date;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class UiController {
    
    @FXML
    private TextArea clockTextArea;


private void refreshClock()
    {
        Thread refreshClock = new Thread()
           {  
              public void run()
              {  
                while (true)
                {
                    Date dte = new Date();
        
                    String topMenuStr = "       " + dte.toString();                       
                    clockTextArea.setText(topMenuStr); 
                           
                    try
                    {
                       sleep(3000L);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  
                }  // end while ( true )
                 
            } // end run thread
         };

         refreshClock.start();
    }

    

    
    public void initialize() {
        
        refreshClock();
    
    }
```

Comment: work through a tutorial on how to use fxml (each and every example explains how/where to initialize stuff that's not configured in the fxml). Note that the manually coded already is wrong: you __must not__ change nodes in an active scenegraph off the fx application thread! Learn about concurrency support in fx

Comment: unrelated: don't use the old Date classes, replace with the newer Local/Date/Time api

Comment: ... all that said: [mcve] please, including application, fxml, controller :)

Answer (score -2):

in javafx you work with events in the `initialize()` method.

E.g. `button.setOnAction(e -> System.Exit(0));` or `clock.onMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("Test"));`

Comment: that's an option (using fxml the preferable way would be to declare the handler in the fxml though), but how is this related to the question? I don't see any event handling involved .. ;) Anyway, please format the code in your answer to make it readable, either in a new line (4 leading spaces) which is my personal preference or inline via backtics. Use the help button to learn about formatting :)