# Editing Text Area within Controller

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, fxml, scenebuilder

I am new to Java and JavaFX. I've created a JavaFX project using SceneBuilder/FXML and I'm attempting to add a realtime clock at the start of the program which works throughout the whole program at the top of the screen. I created a text area and tried to add the clock function from the code we were given but every time I start the program, it always shows up blank. Even doing trying to just use the .setText("string") function manually doesn't work so I think I'm putting the code in the wrong place. If possible, can someone tell me where this code should go or point me in the correct direction?

Here is my main:

```
package application;
import java.lang.ModuleLayer.Controller;
import java.util.Date;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;



public class Main extends Application {
    
    
    
    public static Stage stage = null;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Ui.fxml"));      
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        this.stage = stage;
        stage.show();
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is my controller code:

```
package application;

import java.util.Date;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class UiController {
    @FXML
    private TextArea clockTextArea;
    @FXML
    private TextArea transactionLog;
    @FXML
    private TextField recipentField;
    @FXML
    private Button payButton;
    @FXML
    private Button requestButton;
    @FXML
    private TextField commentField;

    
    
    private void refreshClock()
    {
        Thread refreshClock = new Thread()
           {  
              public void run()
              {  
                while (true)
                {
                    Date dte = new Date();
        
                    String topMenuStr = "       " + dte.toString();                       
                    clockTextArea.setText(topMenuStr); 
                           
                    try
                    {
                       sleep(3000L);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  
                }  // end while ( true )
                 
            } // end run thread
         };

         refreshClock.start();
    }

    
    
    public void initialize() {
        
        TextArea clockTextArea = new TextArea();

        refreshClock();
        
        
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: You can’t update the UI from a background thread.

Comment: hmm ... this looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540928/calling-a-function-on-the-start-of-a-javafx-project-using-scenebuilder (including the errors I commented on) - did you create a new account to repost? If so, don't - instead edit the previous to make it answerable. At the very least, fix the errors that were already spotted .. BTW: creating a local textField and not using it in any way (in initialize) is .. useless.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that whether it is in Swing or JavaFX, when updating the control, it needs to be done in the **event dispatching thread, [EDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)**, otherwise it will not work or throw Exception `Not on FX application thread; currentThread = *`

At this time, you only need to place the code of the update control code in the event dispatch thread for completion. Use the following code in JavaFX

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         //Update the control code of JavaFX and put it here
     }
});
```

So change your code:

```
Date dte = new Date();
String topMenuStr = "       " + dte.toString();  
Platform.runLater(() -> clockTextArea.setText(topMenuStr));
```

and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

One route is to use `Timeline` to handle the clock. It's will be independent of your other code.

**Main**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("primary.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 1080, 720);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

**PrimaryController**

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class PrimaryController {
    
    @FXML Label lblClock;    
    
    Timeline clockHandler;
    
    @FXML
    void initialize()
    {
        Locale locale_en_US = Locale.US ;  
        DateTimeFormatter formatterUS = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale_en_US ) ;

        clockHandler = new Timeline(
                 new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), (ActionEvent event) -> {
                     LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();
                     String outputUs = currentTime.format(formatterUS);
                     lblClock.setText(outputUs);
        }));
        clockHandler.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        clockHandler.play();        
    }
}
```

**Primary FXML**

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1080.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sed.home.javafxrealtimeclock.PrimaryController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar>
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <HBox>
         <children>
            <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Label fx:id="lblClock" text="00:00">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Label>
         </children>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </HBox>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="451.0" layoutY="331.0" text="The other parts of the program here" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```